# get last inserted id from wordpress $wpdb

Tags: wordpress

I would like to get last inserted id after $wpdb->insert().I got a solution with `$wpdb->insert_id();` but unfortunately which retrieves the primary key plus an additional zero.
ie, consider my primary key (or inserted id) is 2 `$wpdb->insert_id();` retruns 20 .whats wrong with this method?anybody can please help me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `insert_id` is a property, not a method. Try it without the `()` at the end, see what you get.

Comment: its not the last ID ! please answer this question

Comment: From the comment for $insert_id in the code: `The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).`. This is the ID from an auto increment. If your inserting into a table without an auto increment you have to already know the ID unless your using UUID rather than INT.